# Как составить запрос в MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Схема документа

```
doc_info: string
wa:[
  wa_flag: int
  ax:[
    ax_info: string,
    de:[
      type: int,
      value: int
    ]
  ]
]
```

На выходе хочется получить список документов:

```
id
doc_info
count of wa
    where wa_flag in [1,2,3]
total count of ax
    where wa_flag in [1,2,3]
total count of de
    where
      wa_flag in [1,2,3]
      de.type == 10 and de.value > 2
      de.type == 50 and de.value > 1
```

[Тестовый набор данных](http://pastebin.com/RYmdFAUf)

Моя попытка сломалась на шаге "total count of ax": [запрос](http://pastebin.com/siXzq191), [ответ](http://pastebin.com/W8Mcv6aM)

Пытался раскручивать, с помощью unwind, с флагом "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays", но на пустых массивах - ломается

Comment: Кажется, сдвинулся с места [запрос](http://pastebin.com/JZ3iUhJW), [ответ](http://pastebin.com/w5ytZe0P)

Answer (score 1):

Запрос

```
db.getCollection('tost').aggregate([
    {
        "$project":{
            "_id": "$_id",
            "doc_info": 1,
            "wa_count": {
                "$sum":{
                    "$map":{
                        "input": "$wa",
                        "as": "w",
                        "in": {
                            "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$$w.wa_flag", 1]}, 1, 0]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "ax_count": {
                "$sum":{
                    "$map":{
                        "input": "$wa.ax",
                        "as": "sub",
                        "in": {
                            "$size": "$$sub"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "de_count": {
                "$sum":{
                    "$map":{
                        "input": "$wa.ax",
                        "as": "ax",
                        "in": {
                            "$sum":{
                                "$map":{
                                    "input": "$$ax.de",
                                    "as": "de",
                                    "in": {
                                        "$size": "$$de"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Ответ

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a48c571b252bcce6cab8aa"),
    "doc_info" : "info_1",
    "wa_count" : 0,
    "ax_count" : 0,
    "de_count" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a48c611b252bcce6cab8ab"),
    "doc_info" : "info_2",
    "wa_count" : 1.0,
    "ax_count" : 0,
    "de_count" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a48c691b252bcce6cab8ac"),
    "doc_info" : "info3",
    "wa_count" : 2.0,
    "ax_count" : 6,
    "de_count" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a48c731b252bcce6cab8ad"),
    "doc_info" : "info4",
    "wa_count" : 1.0,
    "ax_count" : 2,
    "de_count" : 4
}
```